# No such file or directory running docker with .NET core process

Tags: c#, docker, process, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a C# ASP.NET Core application that I deploy with docker on WSL. The dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR ./app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR ./app
COPY ./app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

This "DockerTest" application will attempt to execute the following docker command using `System.Diagnostics.Process`:

```
docker run --rm otherimage args
```

This docker command works when run directly in the WSL terminal, so I know that docker is there and the command is valid.

However, when I run this application in WSL, I get:

```
[Win32Exception]: An error occurred trying to start process 'docker' with working directory '/app/app'. No such file or directory
```

In the "DockerTest" application, I set the `ProcessStartInfo` as such:

```
new ProcessStartInfo("docker", "run --rm otherimage args")
```

I also explicitly set the WorkingDirectory to `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

I've confirmed the working directory exists by adding a pre-check in the code:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory)) { ...
```

So if the working directory exists and docker is installed/available in WSL, what does it think does not exist?

Comment: The error says there's no docker file or executable, not that the folder doesn't exist. Did you install Docker inside WSL ? You need to install the docker CLI even if you want to talk to the Docker engine on Windows

Comment: Yes.  As mentioned, I can execute the docker run command in the WSL terminal directly.  I also can run docker build, so the docker CLI is definitely there.  The issue happens when I try to execute docker via `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Comment: Is Docker Desktop running when you try to run your application? If not, when you try to run `docker` in the terminal you get an error `The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro.
We recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.` Once you start Docker Desktop, the command becomes available. In the Docker Desktop setting you check `Enable integration with my default WSL distro` in Settings, Resources, WSL Integration

Comment: It's not enough to install docker in WSL. You need the docker CLI inside the container. And you need to somehow give it access to a Docker daemon. Either by running one inside the container or by giving it access to the Docker daemon running in WSL. This might help: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/use-docker-kubernetes#:~:text=Docker%2Dfrom%2DDocker%20%2D%20Also,but%20has%20bind%20mounting%20limitations.

Comment: @HansKilian Ah! That makes sense, when I docker exec and look at my container, I see that the docker cli is in fact not there.  Sorry for the confusion, still new to docker.

Answer (score 0):

try like next example:

```
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```